# Start methode if a new Outlook mail is received in C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I have a little problem. 
I'm afraid I don't know where or how to begin.

My project:
When I have a new e-mail in my Outlook mailbox with the subject "START" I want to execute a method.

In the following structure:

```
public void EmailNotification()
{
    if (/* Check every 5 minutes as long as application is running for new mails in Outlook*/ || /* 
        subject contains the string "start" */){
             AnyMethod();
    }
}

public void AnyMethod()
{
    // Do somethink
}
```

I hope my problem is clearly explained.
I am still a relative beginner in C# and am happy for any help.

I am afraid that the exchange server, which I cannot control, is blocking something if I do it with IMAP (because of sercurity rules e.g. untrusted application) but for sure I can try it. Maybe it works.

Comment: Do you need to connect to outlook? Wouldn't it be better to connect directly to the mail server through imap?

Comment: Yes, but I am afraid that the exchange server, which I cannot control, is blocking something.
Because of safety rules.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Application.NewMailEx) event of the Application class from the Outlook object model. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` string to call the `NameSpace.GetItemFromID` method and process the item.

```
void Application_NewMailEx(string EntryIDCollection)
    {    
        Outlook.MailItem newMail = (Outlook.MailItem) Application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

        // do whatever you want with the new email...
    }
```

You may also find the following series of articles helpful:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)

Comment: Do you know why I get "CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property '_Application.Session"

Comment: Make sure you can access the `Application` object instance. This is an instance of the `Application` class, not the class itself